# hibernate generator tag

Tags: nhibernate-mapping

What the exact purpose of  ' native ' in hibernate mapping file of the generator tag
( I know  by using genarator tag, it will genaerate the primarykey values ...)

.......
..........

Answer (score 1):

It uses the generation strategy that is best suited for the database. From the [hibernate docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-id-generator):

> **native** - selects identity, sequence or hilo
>   depending upon the capabilities of the
>   underlying database.

The reason this is necessary is that there is no identity type that is common to all databases. In the case where the database doesn't even support an `int`/`long` identity type, hi/lo generation strategy is necessary, which is a hibernate-generated id.

If you know the specific database you are working with, then you can name a specific identifier generation scheme to use. But for cross-db development, using `native` means the application has more chance of being portable across different dbs.

Comment: ok. thanks for replying.
I understood that
identity related to type.
what about the hilo generation strategy????

Comment: @CHANTI - please see the link I gave to the documentation. It describes the hilo strategy in more detail than is possible here.

Answer (score 0):

native means that the database's means are used to generate the primary key values. E.G. a Sequence in Oracle 10g and AUTO_INCREMENT for mysql.

Hope that helped..